DNS leaks using network namespaces
I am using Ubuntu 22.04.
I am trying to run a WireGuard VPN client inside a network namespace.
I am able to connect to the VPN and route connections but I am getting DNS leaks.
I was running systemd-resolved but I was unable to separate the DNS queries coming from different network namespaces. So, I decided to disable systemd-resolved and also network manager with
systemctl disable --now systemd-resolved.services
systemctl disable --now NetworkManager

and same for the network manager service. So, in theory, at this point I have nothing managing resolv.conf.
After doing that I create the file /etc/netns//resolv.conf with one line only 'nameserver'.
Then I create the WireGuard device in the init network namespace and move it to the newly created namespace (and I have checked that /etc/resolv.conf binds correctly to the DNS I gave it).
Then I configure the WireGuard device and I am able to make connections, and also when I do nslookup wikipedia.org I do see it uses the right DNS, the one from the VPN provider.
The problem is that when I open a browser in that namespace and I go to https://www.dnsleaktest.com/, I am able to see my ISP DNS. But the general traffic does go through the VPN tunnel.
Does anyone know why this configuration doesn't work after disabling systemd-resolved and network manager? I thought this wasn't working because of some management they were doing but even after deactivating I don't know why the wrong DNS is still used. What else could be causing the mount bind of resolv.conf to not work as I would expect?
Answer: It was happening because nscd was running. Disabling it solved the problem.


Make sure that the entirety of your browser is running inside that network namespace. Most large browsers are "single instance" programs; running chrome https://foo will merely connect to an already running instance and ask it to open that URL.

Glibc has an additional abstraction layer above DNS: the 'name service switch' interface, configured through /etc/nsswitch.conf, which can load different hostname lookup modules. (For example, it has a libnss_resolve module that talks to systemd-resolved in a more direct way than "DNS at 127.0.0.53".) Make sure it doesn't have something unexpected enabled.
Use getent (or socket.getaddrinfo() from Python or other languages) for testing this:
getent hosts example.com
getent -s dns hosts example.com
getent -s $module hosts example.com


In addition, Glibc also has its own "name caching daemon," nscd (or sometimes unscd). Most distributions no longer use it, but if it's running, then programs will contact it through a Unix socket in /run – which disregards network namespaces – and the caching daemon will of course use the resolv.conf from its own (i.e. initial) network namespace, giving you the same kind of problem you had with systemd-resolved.


